# Primefaces Datable inline editing issues incase of error when updating

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using datatable inline editing for updating datatable rows. In edit mode if I update values and click submit (Liitle icon on the row with tick mark) and say If there is an error upating, then I see error message but editing mode is gone.

Is there anyway can we enable editmode incase if error occured during update ? Without this feature inline editing doesn't make sense.

Comment: please post your code maybe we can see if there is a mistake on it and also read [how-to-ask ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i fixed it my self.
**This is the fix:-**
In some of my code at row edit handler method throws and Exception make sure we catch it and then set

> FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();

(and probably create a FacesMessage if not there).
 If validationFailed is true the the row will stay in edit mode.
And also ,the above code line need to be put in validation method if we have ( for each component validation method)

Source: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9775

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{Bean.edit}" update=":Form_Mesages :Form" oncomplete="rowEditComplete()"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{Bean.onRowEditInit(datatableVar)}" onstart="rowEditStart() "/>
                    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{Bean.onRowCancel(datatableVar)}" oncomplete="rowEditComplete()"  update=":Form"/>
```

Using ajax...I didn't completely get your point ,if that's what you don't mean,try to post your code if it's possible until we can help you

Comment: Hi, try to not use abbreviations SO is not a chat room it is a place to share knowledge and as such one should make good use of the common language here.

Comment: i am sorry , I didn't know that